# AngularJS show 2 random records

Tags: angularjs

I just started up learning AngularJS and I have no idea how to solve this problem. For example I have 4 records (car, plane, ship, train)  and I only want to show 2 randomly in ng-repeat.

Examples:
1.st. plane, ship
2.nd. car, train
3.rd. train, plane

So how would syntax look like ?

JS:

```
app.controller('WorkCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('work.json').success(function(work) {

        $scope.work = work;

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="work" ng-controller="WorkCtrl">
    <ul class="grid">
        <li ng-repeat="work in work">
            <a href="@{{ work.link }}" target="blank_">
               <div class="background"></div>
               <h3 class="name">@{{ work.name }}</h3>
               <p class="description">@{{ work.description }}</p>
               <img ng-src="@{{ work.image_path }}">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the sample code that demonstrate your problem.

Comment: yes, please show your code. My suggestion would be to write a filter which takes an input array, and returns an array of 2 items randomly selected from the array.

Comment: @EliteOctagon If you make a filter with random values you'll end up with an infinite $digest loop. filters should be idempotent, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939146/non-idempotent-filter-causing-infinite-digest-error

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that.. nor the meaning of idempotent

Comment: @IlanFrumer I tried this and it seemed to work http://plnkr.co/edit/mJ5Q7n24uLnELSNPUB9z?p=preview, but now I can't seem to load it... infinite loop?

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/mJ5Q7n24uLnELSNPUB9z/script.js viewing works fine

Comment: @EliteOctagon You should know this term from the HTTP protocol: http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/idempotency/

Comment: Thanks @IlanFrumer , I actually didn't know the term, but I know the definition. I can see how this would mess with the watcher set on the object.

Comment: @ewing1990 How often you need to re - randomize the list? what is the trigger?

Comment: @IlanFrumer I need re-randomize on each page load/refresh

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="w in work = (work|orderBy:randomize).slice(0, 2)">

$scope.randomize = function () {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hmx2zqex/

Comment: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: It only rewrites the array and deletes all the values except two random values.

Comment: Why is that a problem? It won't modify the model and since other values will not be used in the template, nothing is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I created something like this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.records = ['plane', 'train', 'car', 'submarine'];

}]); 

app.filter('randomSelection', function(){
  return function(inputArray, numItemsToReturn){
    // assuming you pass an array, not doing checking here
    if(!inputArray)
      return inputArray;

    var numItems = inputArray.length;
    var min = 0;
    var max = numItems-1;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

    while (inputArray.length > numItemsToReturn){
      inputArray.splice(random, 1);
    }

    return inputArray;
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="record in records | randomSelection : 2"> 
    {{record}}
</div>
```

Seems to work, no infdigest loop. You may want to add another condition in the while loop to break out so as to avoid an infinite loop.

http://embed.plnkr.co/mJ5Q7n24uLnELSNPUB9z/script.js

Comment: Big thnx for fast response, it works fine and it's just what I needed.

Comment: as Ilan Frumer suggests, this is not a good approach as we are watching an object with ng-repeat and then modifying it with a filter. If you look at the console, you'll see that it is fired multiple times, getting inconsistent results... but if it works for you...

Comment: @EliteOctagon as I said the rule: filters must be idempotent